# $0 \leq Y \leq M$ random variable, $p > 1$. Calculate $\mathbb{E}(Y^p)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expectation

$0 \leq Y \leq M$ random variable, $p > 1$.

Show that

$\mathbb{E}[Y^p] = \int_0^M py^{p-1}\mathbb{P}[Y \geq y] dy$

My attempt:

$\mathbb{E}[Y^p] = \int_0^{\infty} Y d\mathbb{P} = \int_0^{M} Y d\mathbb{P} $

Now I guess I have to use the Change of Variables Formula. I tried to do this but I didn't get the result I should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y^p] = \int_0^{M} y^p f_Y(y)dy\ ,
$$
where $f_Y(y)$ is the pdf of $Y$, and thus equal to $f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}\mathbb{P}[Y<y]=-\frac{d}{dy}\mathbb{P}[Y>y]$. Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y^p] = -\int_0^{M} y^p \frac{d}{dy}\mathbb{P}[Y>y]dy\ ,
$$
and using integration by parts
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y^p] = -\left[y^p \mathbb{P}[Y>y]\right]\Big|_0^M + \int_0^M dy\ p y^{p-1}\mathbb{P}[Y>y]=\boxed{\int_0^M dy\ p y^{p-1}\mathbb{P}[Y>y]}
$$

Comment: Note that this assumes that $Y$ is a continuous random variable, but the question holds for much more general distributions.  The argument can go through pretty much the same way using a Riemann-Stieltjes integral instead of explicitly assuming that a pdf function $f_Y(y)$ exists.